# c / What behaviour would you expect, best practice, signal, thread, process?

Tags: c, pthreads, fork, signals

My source looks like that:

```
keep_going = 1;
struct sigaction action;
memset(&action, '\0', sizeof(action));
action.sa_sigaction = &signal_handler;

if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, NULL) < 0) {
    perror ("sigaction\n");
    return 1;
}

pid_t cpid = fork();

if(cpid == 0)
{
    // child process
    child_process(&p_config_0);
}
else if (cpid < 0)
{
    perror("fork not successful\n");
}
else
{
    // parent process
    pthread_t mgmt_tid;
    int rc_1 = pthread_create(&mgmt_tid, NULL, mgmtSrvcThread, (void *) &p_config_0);

    if(rc_1)
    {
        printf("error: pthread_create() is %d\n", rc_1);
        exit(1);
    }

    parent_process(&p_config_0);
}

void signal_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context)
{
    printf("signal received: %d\n", sig);
    printf("waiting until configuration is done\n");
    keep_going = 0;
    sleep(5);
    printf("done\n");
    keep_going = 1;
}
```

The variable `keep_going` is known by both processes, the child and the parent.
The parent starts another thread, before starting it's normal work. This thread is listening for management information and sets `keep_going` to false to stop both worker processes, the parent and the child. It is working but it feels not right and actually I am not really sure what is happing behind...

As I am installing the signal handler before forking, I think there will be two of them after forking, one for the parent, and one for the child, right? The signal handler sets the variable that controls a `while(keep_going)` loop in both processes.

My question now, I want the thread executing the `mgmtSrvcThread` method to stop both processes when it raises `raise(SIGUSR1)`. And both processes should go on doing their work when the configuration is done inside the thread. Maybe a second signal could be sent or by setting up a timeout. What is the best way of controlling two processes from one thread.

I would be happy to get any help.
Thanks in advance.
nyyrikki

Comment: How is `keep_going` declared so that each process can access the same copy?

Comment: Wow, you discovered the first mistake, the `keep_going` is inside the *.h file included into both files representing the process tasks, like `parent_process(&p_config_0)` and `child_process(&p_config_0)`. I just tried out and both processes could have different `keep_going~ status because as you said, it is a copy. Now, but also the signal_handler is copied, right? So maybe that's why it is working. I think it is messed up, can you provide some better idea of handling that...?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are playing a dangerous game. Not particularly bad, but is it really worth mixing threads, fork and signals ? I mean, mixing threads and signals is enough of a headache. Couldn't you solve this using **just forks / just pthreads** ?

Second, in my opinion signals are a poor, archaic IPC mechanism.

Better mechanisms:

- Message queues, semaphores (threads and processes)
- Condition variables (threads only)

I don't know the exact problem you are solving but in your case I would go with a few threads and some condition variables.

Comment: That's true, I am mixing things. I tried before only with threads, but because I am handling sockets inside the two tasks, I got a `interrupted system call` as you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030310/c-interrupted-system-call-fork-vs-thread. So that's why I wanted to stay with forking, because it was working and I needed to go on somehow.

Comment: @nyyrikki `EINTR` is one of the reasons I am saying you should stay away from signals.

Comment: `sa_flags = SA_RESTART`. No more `EINTR`. Very simple. Always use this.

Comment: @R.. "If a blocked sem_wait() call is interrupted by a signal handler, then it fails with the error EINTR, regardless of whether the SA_RESTART flag was used when establishing the signal handler with  sigaction()". Quoted from TLPI. There are other system calls that do this too.

Comment: Good point. I was just thinking of the sort of IO code that usually is (and usually should be) written without any regard to `EINTR`. Of course you're right and certain things (sleeps, semaphores, etc.) will have to handle it still. Or, you could just make a dedicated signal handling thread and block all signals in all other threads.

Comment: @R.. Exactly: if you *have* to handle signals, do it in one thread and block them everywhere else.

Comment: Guys, thanks so far. I am completely new to C programming. So maybe you could provide me with a little bit more them >_< I am thinking of changing back to `just and only` threads. Will try it out...

Comment: @cnicutar: Sometimes you *want* `EINTR`, and *want* IO code to treat it as an error rather than looping. This can be a very good alternative to pthread cancellation. But otherwise I agree, put the signal handlers in their own thread and then they're free to use any functions, even async-signal-unsafe ones.

Answer (score 1):

The usual mechanism for single-bit cross-thread communication (particularly for resource locking) is via mutexes.  [See this simple example](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzahw/rzahwe18rx.htm).

```
void *theThread(void *parm)
{
   int   rc;
   printf("Thread %.8x %.8x: Entered\n", pthread_getthreadid_np());
   rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   checkResults("pthread_mutex_lock()\n", rc);
   /********** Critical Section *******************/
   printf("Thread %.8x %.8x: Start critical section, holding lock\n",
      pthread_getthreadid_np());
   /* Access to shared data goes here */
   ++sharedData; --sharedData2;
   printf("Thread %.8x %.8x: End critical section, release lock\n",
          pthread_getthreadid_np());
   /********** Critical Section *******************/
   rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   checkResults("pthread_mutex_unlock()\n", rc);
   return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand the next `The variable keep_going is known by both processes, the child and the parent`, what do you mean? According to your code this variable is not shared between  processes, so if it is changed in the parent, it is not changed in the child.

The simplest way is send a signal to the child when parent got SIGUSR1.

Also, think twice when you use signals, threads and fork.

Comment: actually every process keeps a copy of the variable, what you said is right, changing it in the parent would have any effect in the client. but still not solved my problem >_<